# is it possible to hide control properties in designer property grid in c#?

Tags: c#, properties, attributes, custom-controls

I was wondering if is it possible to hide or only show specific properties of a control or custom control on the property grid at design time.

this is what I mean: assume I have a Custom ComboBox

when I'm on the designer view I only would like to see it's DataSource, ValueMember and DisplayMember properties.

is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

There is a BrowsableAttribute that when set to false would hide the property, but since you are deriving from ComboBox, you wouldn't be able to add the attribute since those properties are in the base class. I haven't tried this, so you'll have to, but what might work is if you hide the properties you want to hide by using the new keyword in your custom ComboBox class and applying the Browseable(false) attribute there. But you'd have to do that for every property you want to hide. If that doesn't work, then I guess the answer would be no :).

Comment: I thought of this as a last resort, guess I have no choice but doing it by hand for each property :(